# responsive thumbnail gallery with image preview

Tags: css, image, width, gallery, responsive

I want to ask how to make this kind of image gallery (by fcalderan),

codepen.io/anon/pen/OPMeXM

to be responsive. The reason why I wanted to make it responsive is so that when I need to add another item on the gallery it would line up with the rest of the thumbs/ or stacked when the viewport becomes too narrow. I can't do this alone , thanks to anyone who'll spare some time to help!

Update: I may not need the zoom/window preview to be responsive, rather make the whole gallery responsive when it comes to width so when adding images he thumb would stack and placed below.

Below is the link to the image that may help visualize what I'm trying to achieve.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1FMADgebxAyQkszbkpuVk1PRjQ/view?usp=drivesdk

I'm very sorry guys, thanks Seiko85

Comment: The easiest way is to use an additional library like bootstrap to be able to use a responsive grid. That way you add the respective classes to the dom elements and it should line up. For further help please provide a fiddle with what you tried already. This is not a page where the full work is done for you, but where we're glad to help if you are stuck.

Comment: @Seika85, thanks for the reply, I was hoping to just do it with css alone because I am new to bootstrap and always had some issues with bootstraps media queries. I have done it with just divs and failed to make it responsive the code I made before was way too messy, unlike the way calderas's proportion layout using the description list. I'm sorry I have no jsfiddle to provide but will try to make a layout later. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Bootstrap may be way overhead for what you try. But I wanted to show you a well known responsive grid library. But since you provided us with pretty few information, I just wanted to give you hints where to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your codepen example and added bootstrap as well as respective classes.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/hdqgeuqg/

I added `class="container"` to the `<dl id="simple-gallery">` and `class="col-md-3"` to all `<dt>` elements.

Then some **CSS** adaptions needed to be made, like:

```
dl.container {
    /*height: 488px;*/
    padding: 360px 5px 5px;
    /* ... */
}
dl.container:before { /* ... */ }
dt {
    /*height: 100px;*/
    /* ... */
}
```

---

A more refined/responsive fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hdqgeuqg/3/

Comment: @seiko85 thank you for the fast reply, while we can add thumbnails is it possible that the top /upper part can be responsive so that it will automatically align on the right part of the gallery? Sorry for the late reply. I appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Can you explain more what you want to accomplish? You can play around with my fiddle and update it, so I can see what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Thank you, here is a quick image of what I need to achieve: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1FMADgebxAyQkszbkpuVk1PRjQ/view?usp=drivesdk.

Comment: Hello again Seiko, here is what I came up with,but the responsive/auto width is what I can't figure out.    https://jsfiddle.net/hdqgeuqg/1/

Comment: That's why I recommended Bootstrap, every `.container` (or every `.row`) spans a new 12-column-grid. The classes `.col-(s)-(n)` (where *(s)* is one of the breakpoint identifiers (xs, sm, md, lg), and *(n)* is a number from 1 to 12) describe how many columns of that it will spread across. So you just need to add the respective classes (like `col-xs-6 col-sm-4`) to the thumbnails already having `col-md-3`: https://jsfiddle.net/hdqgeuqg/2/

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer seiko85, this is the kind of layout I've been trying to achieve! will try bootstrap workaround in the meantime, if ever you find a way that makes it auto responsive with the basic css codes do let me know please :), because I also need the code to have no dependencies on bootstrap and such. I appreciate the help, big thanks! :D

Comment: Just look how Bootstrap does it (in its sourcecode). It's mostly a combination of media-queries and classes. Don't be afraid of the amount of selektors and stuff when you look at it, Bootstrap is quite more than just a grid. Just look for `.container`, `.row`, `.row-fluid` and `.col-...` stuff.
I also refined the fiddle a bit and added some media-queries: https://jsfiddle.net/hdqgeuqg/3/

Comment: Thanks for the further improvement of the layout, will do check out the rules that bootstrap applied to the columns and rows and have a better understanding. Your help is more than enough Seika85, thanks again! :D